# SVN access structure

Tags: svn

I want to set permission for different users on a same project, but User_1 could see/reach the Folder_1 and User_2 could see/reach only Folder_2.

[image: SVNaccess]

I applied the following structure on the subversion access file but both users could check both folders out because they have access to reach the Project (parent).

```
[Project:/]
User_1 = r/w
User_2 = r/w

[Project:/Folder_1]
User_1 = r/w

[Project:/Folder_2]
User_2 = r/w
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please, **read carefully** the whole [Path-Based Authorization](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) chapter in SVN-Book
2. After it you'll be able to detect 2 errors and at least 1 *imperfection* in your rules, which give you not the result you expect, but according to defined rulesets

- **If** `Repository` is SVN-repo **and** `/Project/*` is *tree inside* repo, you have incorrect sections headers, because in `[A:/B/C/D/E]` A means **REPOSITORY NAME** and *only repository*
- If some of your ACL-rules in child folder are identical to parent folder rule, you can skip it's definition - they are inherited in nested tree by default
- `No access` in authz-file is empty list of access rules for defined user
- Possible access rules are `rw`, `r`,

Thus, such a set of rules for solving the problem follows from the mentioned above

```
[/]
User_1 = rw
User_2 = rw

[Repository:Project/Folder_1]
User_2 =

[Repository:Project/Folder_2]
User_1 =
```

As alternative `[/]` you *can* have `[Repository:]` section, but in this case you have to define base ACL for each added repository on server (every SVN-server can have any amount of served repos) instead of inheritance from root-rules and tuning only needed parts of them